# Parsing error when trying to parse comma-delimited key-value pairs with values containing list separated by commas

Tags: regex, scala, parsing

I have this class:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.JavaTokenParsers

class RequestMappingParser extends JavaTokenParsers {
  def key: Parser[String] = "value" | "method" | "consumes" | "params"
  def singleValue: Parser[String] = """[^),]*""".r
  def multipleValues: Parser[String] = "{" ~ repsep(ident, ",") ~ "}" ^^ {
    case "{" ~ lst ~ "}" => lst.mkString(", ")
  }
  def value: Parser[String] = multipleValues | singleValue
  def keyValue: Parser[(String, String)] = (key ~ "=" ~ value).map {
    case k ~ _ ~ v => k -> v
  }
  def commaDelimitedSeq: Parser[Map[String, String]] = repsep(keyValue, ",").map(_.toMap)

  def requestMapping: Parser[MethodRequestMapping] = ("@RequestMapping(" ~ commaDelimitedSeq ~ ")").map {
    case _ ~ map ~ _ =>
      val consumes = if (map.contains("consumes")) Some(map("consumes")) else None
      val value = if (map.contains("value")) Some(map("value")) else None
      val method = if (map.contains("method")) Some(map("method")) else None
      val params = if (map.contains("params")) Some(map("params")) else None
      new MethodRequestMapping(value = value, method = method, consumes = consumes, params = params)
  }
}
```

I have this test:

```
  test("@RequestMapping – params") {
    val parser = new RequestMappingParser()
    val requestMappingStr = """@RequestMapping(
                   |  value = "/ex/bars",
                   |  params = { "id", "second" },
                   |  method = GET)""".stripMargin
    val parseResult = parser.parse(parser.requestMapping, requestMappingStr)
    val result = parseResult.get
    assert(result.value.get.equals("\"/ex/bars\""))
    assert(result.method.get.equals("GET"))
    assert(result.params.get.equals("{ \"id\", \"second\" }"))
  }
```

But the test is failing with this parsing error:

```
[3.18] failure: ')' expected but ',' found

  params = { "id", "second" },
                 ^
```

I am using Scala 2.13.  What do I have wrong here?

Comment: Which scala version did you use?

Comment: Scala Version 2.13

Answer (score 0):

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.JavaTokenParsers

class RequestMappingParser extends JavaTokenParsers {
  def key: Parser[String] = "value" | "method" | "consumes" | "params"
  def singleValue: Parser[String] = """[^),]*""".r
  def multipleValues: Parser[String] = "{" ~ repsep(stringLiteral, ",") ~ "}" ^^ {
    case "{" ~ lst ~ "}" => "{ " + lst.mkString(", ") + " }"
  }
  def value: Parser[String] = multipleValues | singleValue
  def keyValue: Parser[(String, String)] = (key ~ "=" ~ value).map {
    case k ~ _ ~ v => k -> v
  }
  def commaDelimitedSeq: Parser[Map[String, String]] = repsep(keyValue, ",").map(_.toMap)

  def requestMapping: Parser[MethodRequestMapping] = ("@RequestMapping(" ~ commaDelimitedSeq ~ ")").map {
    case _ ~ map ~ _ =>
      val consumes = if (map.contains("consumes")) Some(map("consumes")) else None
      val value = if (map.contains("value")) Some(map("value")) else None
      val method = if (map.contains("method")) Some(map("method")) else None
      val params = if (map.contains("params")) Some(map("params")) else None
      new MethodRequestMapping(value = value, method = method, consumes = consumes, params = params)
  }
}
```